Input/Output Impedance for ALI
Consider these circuits from Paul Horowitz "Traité de l'electronique" page.238:

I want to derive the expressions they made for \$ Z_e, Z_s \$ for both circuits:
So I think the op amp is equivalent to this model :

So in this model we have a general formula that :\$\frac{V}{V_e} = \frac{A}{1+AB}\$ i considered the output resistance is zero, otherwise it would appear in that expression, so A is the op-amp gain, B is the feedback, so i thought that since \$B = R_2\$ for the left circuit, \$\frac{V_e}{I_e} = Z_e = \frac{V_e}{\frac{V_e - AV}{R_i}} = \frac{V_e}{V_e \cdot \frac{1-\frac{A^2}{1+AB}}{R_i}} \$
Which is definetly not what they got, my question is what should i do to get what they have?
EDIT : My answers
For the right circuit i used the superposition theorem, i supposed that R2 doesnt exist and found out the first impedance, then i supposed R1 doesnt exist and found the impedance which is equal to the left circuit impedance thus : \$Z_e = R_1 + \frac{R_2}{1+A} \$
As for the output impedances i dont understand where should i get the open-loop feedback impedance could it be just R2 for the left circuit?


for the left circuit ...  what should i do to get what they have?

Well, I already went though this before with you. I prefer to note the opamp output current in the circuit. It keeps me from making mistakes.
Look at the following diagram:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The KCL is:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_o}{R_2}&=I_o+\frac{V_i}{R_2}
\end{align*}$$
And you know that:
$$V_o=-A\cdot V_i$$
The resistance seen by \$V_i\$ is \$R_i=\frac{V_i}{I_i}\$. Note that in this circuit, \$I_i=-I_o\$. (They are pointing oppositely to each other.)
So let's use Python/SymPy:
eq1 = Eq( vo/r2, io + vi/r2 )
eq2 = Eq( vo, -A*vi )
simplify( vi / -solve([ eq1, eq2 ],[ vo, io ])[io] )
r2/(A + 1)

That's how you get it.
Note: I'll add my solution to the right side as a hidden set of Python/SymPy code:

    eq1 = Eq( vo/r2, io + vi/r2 )


    eq2 = Eq( vm/r1 + vm/r2, vi/r1 + vo/r2 )


    eq3 = Eq( vo, -A*vm )


    ratsimp( vi / ( (vi - solve([ eq1, eq2, eq3 ], [ vo, io, vm ])[vm]) / r1 ) )


    r1 + r2/(A + 1)


Thanks again periblepsis, can you tell me why what i did is going to lead me to nowhere?

@KnowledgeSeeker I'd prefer to let you clean your own house. You know better than I do how you think about things. And you can see how I'm thinking here. So you are in a better position than I am to find your mental errors.

Yes definetly, is it ok if i answer for the second circuit and check the validity of my proof?

@KnowledgeSeeker Sure. Please do. And edit your process into your question, if you like. :)

Hii, i did it sorry couldnt do that yesterday night i was revising control theory
